# Cannon MG 3550 printer driver issues

Tags: drivers, printing

I am running Ubuntu 16.04

I have got my Cannon MG3550 printer working, but there are problems.

1: in the settings i cant seem to select A5 paper.

2: when printing numerous pieces at once it stops, with the paper still in the system, but the actual printing job is finished, forcing me to hit the cancel button thus cancelling the job.

have i installed the wrong driver? 
please give me a step by step guide or some terminal commands,the fix this.

Comment: "Have I installed the wrong driver?" How should we know if you don't say what you installed?

Comment: Is there a terminal command to help me find out?